# MySQL Where Conditon

Tags: mysql, database, performance

In MySQL DB, I have one problem.

```
Table1 : Name1 - Name2; 
Table2: User;

Select ...... 
WHERE Table1.(Name1, ” ”, Name2) = Table2.User;
```

Any help how to connect table Name1 to table Name2 into one, and then make equal to user, because I get an error.

Comment: its like Name1 (Jhon), Name2(Jhonson), User(Jhon Jhonson)

Comment: google for function concat()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `CONCAT` function.

```
SELECT ...
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON CONCAT(t1.Name1, ' ', t1.Name2) = t2.User
```